# Detect WIN+PRINTSCREEN but not PRINTSCREEN

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I have:

- Screeshoter freeware that detects <kbd>PRINTSCREEN</kbd> and does a screenshot
- Autohotkey that calls WindowsSnippingTool with <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>PRINTSCREEN</kbd>:

  ```
  #PrintScreen::
  Run, "C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-snippingtool-app_...\SnippingTool.exe"
  Return
  ```

Problem: when I hit <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>PRINTSCREEN</kbd>, then WindowsSnippingTool starts (normal) but **Screenshoter is also triggered because it detects** <kbd>PRINTSCREEN</kbd> anyway!

How to prevent the latter to happen?

Comment: Choose another key combination for that freeware.

Comment: @harrymc for Screenshoter, not possible. But this portable lightweight freeware is really useful, it quietly (without any GUI) just saves the screen as a JPG or PNG on Desktop (without asking anything).

Comment: The product you are using does a very low-level key detection if it competes with AutoHotKey, so there is no way to block it. Your choice as I see it is to get another screenshooter (there are many), or set Autohotkey with another key combination.

Comment: You're probably right @harrymc. Any idea of replacement screenshoter (portable freeware+working on Win7+noGUIdisplayed+just one keyboard press saves JPG or PNG directly to desktop without popup/dialog) on the top of your head? (if not I'll look or post on softwarerecs.SE)

Answer (score 0):

The product you are using does a very low-level key detection if it can compete
with AutoHotKey, so there is no way to block it.

Your choice as I see it is to get another screenshooter (there are many),
or set Autohotkey with another key combination.

If you are looking for another screenshooter, I like
 [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/)  which is free and open source and
even [reasonably portable](http://getgreenshot.org/faq/is-greenshort-really-portable/).

You may find many others among
[Greenshot alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/greenshot/)
or
[Best Free Screen Capture Tool](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-screen-capture-tool.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution/trick, via [Key remapping](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm):

```
#PrintScreen::F13  ;; Trick to avoid Win+PrintScreen to also trigger Screenshoter (that detects PrintScreen)
#F13::
Run, "C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-snippingtool-app...\SnippingTool.exe"
Return
```